# How to display the contents of an array as a list?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, socket.io

I'd like to output the contents of an array as a list:

*value*

*value*

*value*

However, it's currently outputting the array like this:

*value,value,value*

What can I change to display the array contents as a vertical list?

For context, this is displaying an array that updates by adding/removing items based on connections/disconnections to a server. So, when a user connects, their name is added to the array, when they disconnect, the array is wiped and all connected clients send their username back to the array, updating it. The below code simply displays these changes.

HTML:

```
<section class="membersList">
  <div class="dispUser"></div>
</section>
```

CSS:

```
.membersList {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    background: #ACD8F0;
    width: 150px;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    overflow: auto;
    float: right;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
socket.on('theitems', function (data) {
      $('.dispUser').html('<p>' + data + '</p>');
      console.log(data);
    });
```

If I replace `.html` with `.append`, it will display it as a list, but will show the changes of the array as they happen, rather than replacing it as a whole, which is what I want.

Comment: Please show the output of `console.log(data)`, and also describe what you mean by _"show the changes of the array as they happen, rather than replacing it as a whole"_.

Comment: When one client joins the server, their name is sent to an array in the server. As more join, their names are added to the array. When one leaves, the array is wiped clean and still-connected clients send their names back to the array, "updating" it. The console for when this happens is seen [here](https://ibb.co/nckFfMK).
If I use `.append`, each time the array is altered, the specific change, as per the console, is displayed.

Comment: So it sounds like your function should clear the contents of `<div class="dispUser">` before it appends anything. Would that fix it?

Comment: Unfortunately, not; [this](https://ibb.co/3CRXMdW) is what is displayed on the HTML when `.append` is used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue with your code is that you're trying to directly print an array, which gets converted to a string and so you get the result you're seeing.

You can get the result you want by *iterating* over the array and inserting a paragraph for each item in it. Here is an example:

```js
const data = [5,6,7,8,9];
const list  = document.getElementById('list');
 
window.onload = () => {
  list.innerHTML = data.map(i => `<li>${i}</li>`).join('');
};
```

```html
<ul id="list"></ul>
```

Comment: This code, specifically, didn't work, but the idea of iterating over each element like this worked for me. Thank you! (And thanks to all who helped).

Answer (score 0):

You can use a list in html:

`<div class="dispUser"><ul></ul></div>`

```
socket.on('theitems', function (data) {
      $('.dispUser ul').html('<li>' + data + '</li>');
      console.log(data);
    });
```

Comment: This looked like it would work, however, it's now displaying it exactly the same but with a bullet point.

Comment: So you can use a little css `li {list-style-type: none;}`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the `.html()` method.

The `html()` method sets or returns the content (innerHTML) of the selected elements.

When this method is used to return content, it returns the content of the FIRST matched element.

You need to append the element not change the inner content of it.

Try this:

```
const data = [5,6,7,8,9];
$.each(data, function(i, obj){
        $(".dispUser").append(`<p>${obj}</p>`)
});
```

Comment: I also tried this before posting the question, however, it causes the output to become a mixture of what I want and what I do not.

Comment: Can you be more specific?

Comment: Apologies for my typo I have corrected my solution. You can go ahead with that.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue today, and I tried the above suggestions without any success.

Brainstorming with a colleague, we used array.toString() to convert the array to a string. Then we added on a

```
.replaceAll(',','<br>')
```

to add line breaks between each entry. Finally we passed that variable to the innerHTML.

It worked for our purposes with only a single line of code outside the innerHTML section.

```js
const myArray = ["Learning", "to", "code", "has", "been", "fun!"];
let myString = myArray.toString().replaceAll(",", "<br>");
let myDiv = document.getElementById("myArrayDiv");
let myInnerHTML = document.createElement("div");
myInnerHTML.innerHTML = `<div><p>${myString}</p></div>`;
myDiv.appendChild(myInnerHTML);
```

```html
<div id="myArrayDiv"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This helped with my problem as well thank you.

```js
// my array of items.
let alphabet = [
 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'
];

// container for holding buttons.
const btnContainer = document.getElementById('buttons');

// This function displays each item wrappped in a button.
function displayAlphabet() {
  window.onload = () => {
   btnContainer.innerHTML = alphabet.map((i) => `<button type='button' class='alphabetBtn'>${i}</button>`).join('');
  };
 }
 displayAlphabet()
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please don't post code-only answers but also add a little textual explanation about how and why it works and what makes it different from the other answers.